# ReactJS - Loading data using Axios + chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, axios

I'm learing react and I'm creating app using react,axios and chartjs. I would like use data from axios to create chart but data load after chart creating. The same problem occurs when I update chart.

To create chart I'm using: `document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')` so I cant't wait with render to finish data loading.

In componentWillMount() I'm loading data using getDataFromServer() so I thought the chart would be created with these data.

In componentDidMount() I'm creating my chart.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.mainCtx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    this.state.mainChart = new Chart(this.state.mainCtx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: this.state.tempsMonthLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 35, 3],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Custom Chart Title'
            }
        }
    });}


getDataFromServer(month) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/avgTempsMonth/'.concat(month))
        .then(res => {
            const tempsMonth = res.data;
            this.setState({ tempsMonth });
            const tempsMonthLabels = []; 
            //
            ..converting data to tempsMonthLabels
            //
            this.setState({ tempsMonthLabels });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        })
}

handleChange = event => {
    this.state.currentMonth = event;
    this.getMonthTempsFromServer(event); 
    this.state.mainChart.data.labels = this.state.tempsMonthLabels; 
    this.state.mainChart.update();
}
```

What can I do to load the data before creating chart?
Thanks for avdice.

Comment: I dont see the any call to `getDataFromServer(month)` method inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: `getDataFromServer(month)`is in `componentWillMount()`. I have tried use this method in `componentDidMount` but it don't resolve problem.

Comment: I think thats probably because chart.js doesn't recognize the changes on the react component state object, have you imported `react-chartjs` component into your application. refer this link for more info , https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from server by axios is an asynchronous function.You will never know exact time of when data will receive.

So what you should do is, create the chart after you received all data from the server.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.mainCtx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    getDataFromServer(this.state.defaultMonth);//There should be a default value for initial load
}


getDataFromServer(month) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/avgTempsMonth/'.concat(month))
      .then(res => {
          const tempsMonth = res.data;
          this.setState({ tempsMonth });
          const tempsMonthLabels = []; 
          //
          ..converting data to tempsMonthLabels
          //
          this.setState({ tempsMonthLabels });
          this.setState({ isLoading: false });

          //// Create Chart over here after you received all data

          let mainChart = new Chart(this.state.mainCtx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: this.state.tempsMonthLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 35, 3],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Custom Chart Title'
                }
            }
          });
          this.setState({mainChart});
          ////
      })
}

handleChange = event => {
    this.state.currentMonth = event;
    this.getMonthTempsFromServer(event); 
    this.state.mainChart.data.labels = this.state.tempsMonthLabels; 
    this.state.mainChart.update();
}
```

Comment: Actually, getting data from the server using javascript is non-blocking